# How can I stop Owl carousel from rewinding? I just want a seamless loop

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I make the Owl carousel from rewinding? I just want a continuous loop. Do I need to write a full callback for something that should already included in the plugin? I tried to use the loop: true; no luck.

Comment: if a slider plugin doesn't have features you want, use another one that does. It's not like they are hard to find

Comment: thanks.  wish that was a good solution. However, this slider works best with the head.js script I use.

Comment: Did you try 'rewindNav: false'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As an example, try this setting

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
  autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
  items : 4,
  rewindNav:false //**This

});
```

Comment: thank you. Successfully removed the rewind functionality. We're almost there. Now it has to loop back to the first frame. This is something that should have been a parameter in the plugin.

Comment: This is not an option in owl carousel version 1.33 but it is in v2, in beta now. [owlcarousel v2](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/basic.html)

Comment: Yes it is, I just found this out! Thank you for all your help! This saves a ton of time. I wish they would have told me earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same error and found a quick fix for it. You can use **rewindSpeed: 0** with **rewindNav : true**.

I tested with these settings:

```
$("#owl-slider-hero").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay : 5000, 
    lazyLoad:true,
    navigation : false,
    slideSpeed : 500,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem : true,
    rewindNav : true,
    rewindSpeed: 0
});
```

By doing so, the script still rewinds, but you can hardly see it. The change is not smooth as in a continuous loop, but it is quite close.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Before that,set loop to false.Then it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items:4,
        lazyLoad:true,
        nav:true,
        loop:false,
        navRewind:false,
        margin:10
    });
})
```

Comment: is `navRewind` a know parameter ? or it was meant to be `rewindNav` ?